# navigator.navigate not reloading flatlist

Tags: reactjs

Consider this Home.js

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const Home = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const {count} = route.params;

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

   const getUsers = (count) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?page=${currentPage}&results=${count}`)
      .then(res => {
        //setUsers(res.data.results);
        setUsers([...users, ...res.data.results]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemWrapperStyle}>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = {0.5} onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('Details', {it: item})
        }>
          <Image style={styles.itemImageStyle} source={{ uri: item.picture.large }}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.contentWrapperStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.txtNameStyle}>{`${item.name.title} ${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.txtEmailStyle}>{item.email}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderLoader = () => {
    return (
      isLoading ?
        <View style={styles.loaderStyle}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#aaa" />
        </View> : null
    );
  };

  const loadMoreItem = () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers(count);
  }, [currentPage]);

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#000" />
      <FlatList
        data={users}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.email}
        ListFooterComponent={renderLoader}
        onEndReached={loadMoreItem}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

How do i extract out below as separate module and everything should work as before.

```
   const getUsers = (count) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?page=${currentPage}&results=${count}`)
      .then(res => {
        //setUsers(res.data.results);
        setUsers([...users, ...res.data.results]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In react's word, instead of refactor API fetching functioning to a JS module, it's a better idea to refactor it to a custom hook.

In this case, since the the `axios` fetch depends on both `currentPage` and `count`, these will be the dependency for the custom hook. The implementation will be as followed:

```
const useGetUsers = (currentPage, count) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const fetchResult = await axios
                .get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?page=${currentPage}&results=${count}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    return res.data.results
                })
            setUserData((prevUser) => [...prevUser, ...fetchResult])
            setIsLoading(false)
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [currentPage, count])

    return [isLoading, userData]
}
```

Finally, you can replace

```
  // NOTE: THESE ARE TO BE REMOVED!!
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  // original implementation
  const getUsers = (count) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    axios.get(`https://randomuser.me/api/?page=${currentPage}&results=${count}`)
      .then(res => {
        //setUsers(res.data.results);
        setUsers([...users, ...res.data.results]);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  };

  // and the useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers(count);
  }, [currentPage]);
```

with just

```
const [isLoading, users] = useGetUsers(currentPage, count)
```

Bonus point is to add a `try/catch` block around the `axios` call. (or just the `catch` promise callback function in `axios`.

Lastly, see the fix in action in CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-glade-vhzj72

Cheers

Comment: Now the code is like this, but it says currentPage is read only:   const [currentPage, users] = useGetUsers(currentPage, count)
  
  const loadMoreItem = () => {
    //setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    currentPage = currentPage + 1;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#000" />
      <FlatList
        data={users}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.email}
        ListFooterComponent={renderLoader}
        onEndReached={loadMoreItem}
        onEndReachedThreshold={10}
      />
    </>
  );
};

Comment: This happens on call of loadMoreItems

Comment: If i change loadMoreItems to   const loadMoreItem = () => {
    useGetUsers(currentPage+1, count);
  }; The list become static, ie when I scroll down in my cellphone then I get:  ERROR  Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: One change I made was I used export in front of your declaration: export const useGetUsers = (currentPage, count) => { .... code ...}

Comment: Looks like I can call "const [isLoading, users] = useGetUsers(currentPage, count)" only once at page load, If I reach down the list I get invalid hook call. What is the solution to this, The function has to be called again and again as user reaches end of page..

Comment: Also when first time the function is called the value of currentPage is undefined. How do I make it 0 or 1?

Comment: Did you leave the `const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);` in the original place? since you gave it a `1` then `currentPage` should've been initialized with `1` during initial rendering.

Comment: I cant keep original declaration because since the line you gave has declaration of currentpage, it throws error, currentPage is already declared.

Comment: Here is a CodeSandbox I randomly created with your stuff. You are right I absolutely missed the part where when you click the next page the new user result should be merged with the existing user result. Also I never used `react-native` before so it could use a lot of improvement. https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-glade-vhzj72

Comment: Hey @user204069, just a kind reminder to let me know if the link above works for your scenario!